# Memory leak due to Window.EfectiveValues retention

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, garbage-collection, profiling

I'm experiencing a memory leak in my WPF application.

I want to GC my DiffViewControl, but it's retained by the `Window.EffectiveValues` instance.
[image]

Do you know how could I clean this obsolete reference and then the DiffViewControl can be GC'd?

Comment: Do you have a binding that is still active?

Comment: @RonBeyer: I don't think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem after reading this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1283a5da-48c2-4398-9064-a92f569d657d/wpf-textboxfocus-results-in-usercontrol-garbage-collection-problem?forum=wpf

My problem is that if **I close the WPF window, and a textbox in that window has the focus, the textbox is leaked**, so the entire window is leaked.

The **solution** in my case is *removing the focus from any textbox in the window before closing it.*

```
Keyboard.ClearFocus();
```

Comment: Interesting, this also seems to the case for WPF UserControls when used in MVVM views.  I have had entire View with dataContext() leaked because I was not calling  Keyboard.ClearFocus(); before attempting to unload a view from the main window.   Without your answer, I could have spent days diagnosing this issue.